# React - error result map is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, api

- Framework: React
- Error type: result.map is not a function

I am following the book Road to learn React, I tried the below code with hacker news API it worked well but it is not working with this API. I don't know why I'm getting this error, please help.

Link to my sandbox --> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setup-forked-q0hti?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
    
// API chunks
const PATH_BASE = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
const PATH_SEARCH = "/search";
const PARAM_SEARCH = "query=";
const DEFAULT_QUERY = "redux";
    
//const url = `${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${DEFAULT_QUERY}`;
//console.log(url);
    
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: null
    };
    this.hitStories = this.hitStories.bind(this);
  }
   
  // handling the local state value
  hitStories(result) {
    this.setState({
      result
    });
  }
    
  // lifecycle method
  // Note: componenetDidMount runs after the render method
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${DEFAULT_QUERY}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json_result) => this.hitStories(json_result))
      .catch((error) => error);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    const { result } = this.state;

    if (!result) {
      return null;
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Fetch API in React</h2>
        {result.map((
          item 
        ) => (
         <div>
           {item.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
export default App;
```

Comment: Actually, this.state.result is an object so you can't iterate over it.

Comment: ```result``` variable is an object, not an array. You should change it to: ```Object.values(result).map((item) => (```, which will create an array of all the values

Comment: @szczocik thanks it fixed the error, but its not mapping the list of titles (present in the api). What im missing ?

Comment: @YashMarmat, what is the shape of the ```item``` when you iterate through it?

Comment: @szczocik i just used it as random variable, i have given a link to my sandbox above, hope that helps to encounter my issue.

Comment: In the sandbox, the fetch returns an empty object. If you remove the search query parameter from the URL to get all the items, it renders them correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/react-setup-forked-qig1h
Maybe the query would have to be updated?

Comment: @szczocik thanks for fixing that, i too confused about this parameter issue but the same code works very well with hacker news api. This sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fetching-api-part-1-rendering-list-vsbzk works very well with all parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` is used on an array, your `result` is not an array but an object. Try this:

```
render() {
  const { result } = this.state;

  return result ? (
    <div>
      <h2>Fetch API in React</h2>
      { Object.values(result).map((item) => (
        <div>{item.title}</div>
      ))
      }
    </div>
  ): null;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this fixed the error but its not mapping the list of titles (present in the api). What im missing ?